# Seam starting Context a few times a second even idle

Tags: jsf, log4j, seam

i just want to know if this is a normal behavior. I have roughly two times a second a new context instantiated with no one accessing the server 24/7 ..

```
13:17:27,217 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.ruleBasedPermissionResolver
13:17:27,218 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.identity
13:17:27,218 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.web.session
13:17:27,713 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.ruleBasedPermissionResolver
13:17:27,713 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.identity
13:17:27,713 INFO  [Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.web.session
```

So should i adjust the log to warn for seam or is there something wrong?

thx

Comment: These log messages are generated when someone calls `Contexts.startup(ScopeType.SESSION)`. AFAIK Seam calls it in `SeamListener.sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)`, in other words, normally it happens only when there is http activity -- users creating sessions. Are you sure there is no activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listed only the requests to the page. If only static resources were accessed it wasn't in the jboss log.

In the jboss-seam.jar the class IdentityRequestWrapper or IdentityWrapper (depending on the seam version) i replaced

```
identity = (Identity) request.getSession().
     getAttribute(Seam.getComponentName(Identity.class));
```

with

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null){
identity = (Identity) session.
     getAttribute(Seam.getComponentName(Identity.class));
}
```

the sessions are no longer created for static content